# Strange output from terminal `exit` command is this a virus?

Tags: macos, terminal, virus

I don't think that I have seen this before, but whenever I run `exit` in terminal I get a very strange output.

This is what it looks like:

```
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

And when I remove `~/.bash_sessions` I get this output.

```
logout
Saving session...-bash: ~/.bash_sessions/EBDD3E18-8D29-42DA-B32C-DD4491951FC0.session: No such file or directory
touch: ~/.bash_sessions/EBDD3E18-8D29-42DA-B32C-DD4491951FC0.historynew: No such file or directory
-bash: history: ~/.bash_sessions/EBDD3E18-8D29-42DA-B32C-DD4491951FC0.historynew: cannot create: No such file or directory

...copying shared history...cp: ~/.bash_sessions/EBDD3E18-8D29-42DA-B32C-DD4491951FC0.history: No such file or directory

...saving history...cat: ~/.bash_sessions/EBDD3E18-8D29-42DA-B32C-DD4491951FC0.historynew: No such file or directory
-bash: ~/.bash_sessions/EBDD3E18-8D29-42DA-B32C-DD4491951FC0.history: No such file or directory
-bash: ~/.bash_sessions/EBDD3E18-8D29-42DA-B32C-DD4491951FC0.historynew: No such file or directory
truncating history files...
...completed.
shlock: open(~/.bash_sessions/shlock6026): No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

The other thing is it recreates the `.bash_sessions` folder if it got removed.

Is this some kind of virus or just that I haven't paid that much attention to it, or is this something that Apple added in El Capitan (I'm running OS X 10.11 Build 15A262E) or what else could it be?

Also when I run `login <myusername>` then I run `exit` I do not get this odd output. It only seems to be when closing out of terminal.

Note: I have replaced `/Users/myusername` with `~/` instead. I have also removed my .bash_profile to make sure it wasn't that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This seems to be a change to `Bash Session` in OS X El Capitan. See [Bash sessions](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/397uep/changes_to_bash_sessions_and_terminal_in_el/)

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32418438/4459346) question in SE.

Comment: Ah, Thanks for that! Glad to know it is an OS based thing!

Comment: Please include all relevant details from pages you’re referring to. They might go away, making your answer incomplete.

Answer (score 8):

had the same problem. 
Under terminal preferences->profiles -> shell. Select appropriate action to perform under "when the shell exits" menu. 
Fixed my issue.

Comment: To just ignore the message and just exit the Terminal, under "When the steel exits:" select "Close if the shell exited cleanly".

Answer (score 0):

The last line of /etc/bashrc on the mac reads:

`[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"`

So to disable all the craziness in the Apple Terminal on exit:

`sudo mv /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal /etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal-disabled`

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was happening because I was using `exit` inside of a bash script that I had wrapped/converted into a function. As soon as I replaced `exit` with `return` the issue went away.

Comment: This doesn' answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can add an alias to your shell-profile (like .bashrc) such as:

alias off='exit 0 >/dev/null'

When you use 'off', it exits with those extra messages discarded.

All you get is the 'logout' line, sent to 2>/dev.tty